# How to set custom Date format in SimpleXmlConverter for Retrofit 1.9.0?

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, date-formatting, simple-framework

I'm trying to parse xml-answer via Retrofit and SimpleXMLConverter to annotated object and need to process custom-formated date.

It is quite simple when you're parsing Json with Gson.
Just pass GsonBuilder with custom date format set in GsonConverter.

```
Converter converter = new GsonConverter(
    new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT_STRING).create()
);
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
   .setEndpoint(URL)
   .setConverter(converter);
```

But when you deal with XML and SimpleXMLConverter it's not that simple.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only option i found is @Commit - annotation.
Get Date as string and then parse it in @Commit-annotated method:

```
public class ParsedObject {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT);

    private Date mDate;

    @Element(name = "date")
    private String mXmlDate;

    @Commit
    private void parseDate() {
        if(mXmlDate != null) {
            try {
                mDate = SDF.parse(mXmlDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // do something
            } finally {
                mXmlDate = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```